# How to Load HTML File using web service including its css file in WebBrowser in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating an application in which I am loading HTML file on web browser. But I am not getting the css file.

Comment: _please give me solution_ is not a good way to ask a question. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first..

Comment: i have stored file .HTML,css in isolated storage.and   Web Browser.Navigate(new Uri("html/Important Application Information.html", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, WebBrowser will not load html content like *.js and *.css from storage. 
You can manually read it and include to your html page.